# How to subtract one date from an array of dates?

Tags: java, arrays, date, time

So, I have an array of dates that I asked for from the user. I want to do a days elapsed function to delete certain entries by checking the days elapsed. This wouldn't be too bad with only one date but I can't figure out how to do this with an array of dates unfortunately. It is possible I am overlooking something basic as I am a beginner.

```
int[] dates;
int time;
int long;
Date now = new Date();

time = (int) (new Date().getTime() / 1000L);
diff = dates - time;
```

This last line of code is clearly incorrect and gave me an error. What do I do to correct this?

Thanks for putting up with a noobie.

Comment: Are you comparing all the dates against a single other date (such as today), or against each other? In other words, do you want to delete some items in the array if they happened too far back in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are correct.

- You are not handling arrays properly, as you must loop through an array.
- You are not handling Date objects properly, as they cannot be subtracted using the HYPHEN-MINUS "-" character.

### Study

I suggest doing some more study. The free-of-cost [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) provided online by Oracle is a good place to start, as is the [Head First Java](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009205.do) book.

---

### Collections

You can use basic arrays in Java if you wish, but the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) objects are much more useful.

### Joda-Time

You can use the [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) & [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) classes bundled with Java, but they are not recommended because of bad design and implementation. [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is an open-source third-party library commonly used instead.

In the future with Java 8, the Date/Calendar classes will by supplanted by the new [java.time.* classes](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). These classes were inspired by Joda-Time but are re-architected.

### No Need For Elapsed

If you just want to find the input dates that are too old (or old enough, you didn't say which), then you don't need to calculate elapsed time. Instead, calculate the date-time of the moment at which the inputs became too old. Then compare each input to see if it came before or after that moment.

### Add To New Collection

Another tip: Rather than delete the ones you don't want, simply add the ones you do want to a *new* collection. Makes your code easier to understand and easier to debug.

### Standard Format

Joda-Time by default renders date-times as a string by using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. You see this in the console output below. Joda-Time has many other formats built in, and you may define your own formats too.

### Example Code

Here is some example code to get you going. Using Joda-Time 2.3, running in Java 7.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );

java.util.List<DateTime> dateTimesInput = new ArrayList<DateTime>();
dateTimesInput.add( new DateTime( 2001, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, timeZone ) );
dateTimesInput.add( new DateTime( 2014, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9, timeZone ) );
dateTimesInput.add( new DateTime( timeZone ).minusDays( 2 ) );

// Calculate the moment of a month ago, in desired time zone. Include all of that moment’s day, so go back to first moment of the day.
DateTime monthAgo = new DateTime( timeZone ).minusMonths( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();

// Loop the dates input. If any are less than a month old, keep them.
java.util.List<DateTime> keepers = new ArrayList<DateTime>();
for(DateTime dateTime: dateTimesInput){
    if( dateTime.isBefore( monthAgo ) ){
        // Ignore this date-time.
    } else {
        keepers.add( dateTime );
    }
}

// Dump to console.
System.out.println( "Month ago: " + monthAgo );
for(DateTime dateTime: keepers){
    System.out.println( dateTime );
}
```

When run…

```
Month ago:2013-12-06T00:00:00.000+01:00
2014-01-05T07:08:09.000+01:00
2014-01-04T04:25:31.272+01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate through your array and check each individual entry. Google for loops like for, for each, do while.

I also would recommend not working with array but with list, with a list you can remove invalid entries by just calling the .Remove(object) method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through your array's elements, then do this check for each and every Date in this array. Those dates which are OK (i.e. pass the check), you can add to an ArrayList. Finally loop through the ArrayList and process these as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Date now = new Date();

Date[] datesFromUser = new Date[10];
List<Date> newDatesList = new ArrayList<Date>();

for(Date d: datesFromUser){
    if(d.getTime() > now.getTime()){
        newDatesList.add(d);
    }
}

Date[] dates = new Date[newDatesList.size()];
int index = 0;
for(Date d: newDatesList){
    dates[index++] = d;
}
```